# Geodatabase affecting outcome

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, naming-conventions

Why does my naming convention change depending on where the output is saved?

When I save this to a .gdb, the name of the output is "tif", not final_mosaic.tif.  When I save the same output to a regular Windows directory, the name is correct (final_mosaic.tif).

```
import arcpy, os
inws = r'C:\input' 
outws = r'C:\output.gdb'
rasters = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(inws, topdown = True, datatype="RasterDataset", type = "TIF"):
    for filename in filenames:
        rasters.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(rasters, outws, "final_mosaic.tif", pixel_type = "32_BIT_UNSIGNED", number_of_bands = 1)
```

Comment: You can't save a *TIFF* file into a geodatabase, inside a geodatabase it's (file/personal) geodatabase raster. When you say Final_mosaic.tif it means "in the dataset called Final_Mosaic create a file called 'tif'", but rasters can't be stored in feature datasets so it skips that part, take the extension off for Geodatabase Raster or save somewhere else as a TIFF.

Comment: @ChrisW, I've expanded that to an answer and done my best to substantiate it. I can't find the GeoDatabase Dataset name limitations, do you know where it is?

Comment: Well the rules you quote are on http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000zz000000 but there's also http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018s00000002000000 and I know there's a whole other section on field names somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW, I'll put that link into the answer. Also I forgot the bit about keywords; you can't have a feature class called 'select', 'and', 'or'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a geodatabase you can only store GeoDatabase types, from [Esri Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n00000002000000):

> A key geodatabase concept is the dataset. It is the primary mechanism
>   used to organize and use geographic information in ArcGIS. The
>   geodatabase contains three primary dataset types: Feature classes
>   Raster datasets Tables

So, in a GeoDatabase you can only store Tables, Feature Classes and Rasters. Yes, there are [other objects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018s0000000q000000) like Topology, Terrain, Mosaic Dataset, relationship classes.. that can be stored but the data *storage* come down to the 3.

In [this help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/The_architecture_of_a_geodatabase/003n000000r4000000/) the structure of the database is discussed. Anything you put into a geodatabase *must* be a database type, which you can [add to a GeoDatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_adding_datasets_to_the_geodatabase/003n00000034000000/). Raster is [stored in a GeoDatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000002z000000) as a GeoDatabase raster with the following limitations (Thanks to ChrisW for [the reference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000zz000000)), an overview of the rules:

- Names must not start with numbers or underscores but may contain numbers and underscores.
- Names should not start with sde_, delta_ or gdb_ (there are other reserved ones but these are the main)
- Names should not contain any punctuation characters (%$&.\^etc..) underscore excepted.
- Names must not contain spaces
- You cannot use SQL keywords and other reserved words.

TIFF files are not a GeoDatabase type but they can be imported into a database as a GeoDatabase raster. When you put the '.' in the output dataset (final_mosaic.tif) Esri interprets the instruction as "in the entity `final_mosaic` create a dataset called `tif`", where entity could be a Feature Dataset, database version (SDE) or similar. In a file GeoDatabase rasters can only be stored at the root level so Arc ignores the first part and just uses the second part which is why your tool is creating a dataset called 'tif'.

If you want to export to TIFF, to be readable by GDAL, QGIS etc. you can put the output into a folder:

```
outws = r'C:\output' # NOT a geodatabase.
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(rasters, outws, "final_mosaic.tif", pixel_type = "32_BIT_UNSIGNED", number_of_bands = 1)
```

If you want it in the GeoDatabase then remove the extension:

```
outws = r'C:\output.gdb' # IS a geodatabase.
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(rasters, outws, "final_mosaic", pixel_type = "32_BIT_UNSIGNED", number_of_bands = 1)
```